# Does taking antibiotics make you immune to virus?

Tags: antibiotics, virus

Let's say someone has a virus and the doctor prescribed him to take him antibiotics, while taking the antibiotics can he be effected with another type of virus or the antibiotics will make him immune for some period of time?

Comment: Antibiotics won't work with viruses. They are **anti-bacterias**. Therefore, the antibiotics won't make soy immune against any virus and won't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antibiotics have no effect on viruses.

> Antibiotics do not fight infections caused by viruses like colds, flu,
>   most sore throats, and bronchitis.

https://www.cdc.gov/features/getsmart/

Comment: So what drugs do they use against viruses​?

Comment: @SayedA.There are anti-viral drugs but they're rarely used except in limited circumstances. Mostly, treating viral diseases is a matter of supporting the body and giving it time to heal itself.